# Passing columns and not variables with string format for converting yymmdd to dd-mm-YYYY in python

Tags: python, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark

I have a dataset like the below:

```
df = spark.sql("select '210927' as t_date")
```

Now, I want to convert it to `'27-09-2021'`. Below is my code along with the error:

```
   >>> df = df.withColumn("modifiedDate",datetime.strptime("t_date", "%y%m%d").strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data 't_date' does not match format '%y%m%d'
```

I tried several examples from SO and [this](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/datetime.strptime+YYmmdd) link but didn't work. I am using `Python` with `Pyspark`

Comment: is the input like `210927` exactly? or like `21/09/27`

Comment: Both the existing and the proposed date formats are very problematic. Consider using something sensible like ISO8601.

Comment: If you wanted a day-month-year format why does your format string have a year-month-day format?

Comment: have you tried `datetime.strptime("210927", "%y%m%d").strftime('%d-%m-%Y')`? It looks like this gives the desired output

Comment: @rv.kvetch post your solution as an answer and I will accept it because it is dynamic

Comment: and how do I pass the column for this? It is accepting string only

Comment: hmm, not familiar with the dataset, but you might need to loop through each column value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code worked for me:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, "210927"),
        (2, "210928"),
        (3, "210929"),
        (4, "210930"),
        (5, "211001"),
    ],
    StructType(
        [
            StructField("id", IntegerType(), False),
            StructField("col", StringType(), False),
        ]
    ),
)
 
pDF= df.toPandas()
valuesList = pDF['col'].to_list()
modifiedList = list()
 
for i in valuesList:
...  modifiedList.append(datetime.strptime(i, "%y%m%d").strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
 
pDF['t_date1']=modifiedList
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(pDF)
```

Might help someone someday!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
from datetime import datetime

x = '210927'
year = 2000 + int(x[:2])
month = int(x[2:4])
day = int(x[4:])
dt = datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day)
print(dt)
```

output

```
2021-09-27 00:00:00
```

Comment: why the string slicing if you're using datetime class functionality anyway? rv.kvetch's comment provides a much simpler solution I think.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @balderman but I will have to handle it dynamically which is satisfied by rv.kvetch's answer